# Dynamic Method with ActiveRecord, passing in hash of conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am struggling with the best way to meta program a dynamic method, where I'll be limiting results based on conditions... so for example:

```
class Timeslip < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.by_car_trans(car, trans)
        joins(:car)
        .where("cars.trans IN (?) and cars.year IN (?) and cars.model ILIKE ?", trans, 1993..2002, car)
        .order('et1320')
    end

end
```

Let's say instead of passing in my arguments, i pass in an array of conditions with key being the fieldname, and value being the field value. so for example, I'd do something like this:

i'd pass in [["field", "value", "operator"],["field", "value", "operator"]]

```
def self.using_conditions(conditions)
    joins(:car)
    conditions.each do |key, value|
      where("cars.#{key} #{operator} ?", value)
    end
end
```

However, that doesn't work, and it's not very flexible... I was hoping to be able to detect if the value is an array, and use IN () rather than =, and maybe be able to use ILIKE for case insensitive conditions as well...

Any advice is appreciated. My main goal here is to have a "lists" model, where a user can build their conditions dynamically, and then save that list for future use. This list would filter the timeslips model based on the associated cars table... Maybe there is an easier way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you might find an interest in the [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) gem.

Other than that, use `arel_table` for IN or LIKE predicates :

```
 joins( :car ).where( Car.arel_table[key].in      values )
 joins( :car ).where( Car.arel_table[key].matches value  )
```

you can detect the type of value to select an adequate predicate (not nice OO, but still):

```
 column    = Car.arel_table[key]
 predicate = value.respond_to?( :to_str ) ? :in : :matches # or any logic you want

 joins( :car ).where( column.send predicate, value )
```

you can chain as many as those as you want:

```
 conditions.each do |(key, value, predicate)|
   scope = scope.where( Car.arel_table[key].send predicate, value )
 end
 return scope
```

Comment: Yea, i actually included the squeel gem in my gemfile when looking for a solution... just was hoping to try find something simple, or a way to do this without any extra gems

Comment: arel makes this sort of things quite possible, and helps secure to it. However you can't have a 'universal magic and secure query'... you still have to build things specific to your business rules. Without that, we developpers wouldn't have any more jobs :D

Comment: Can you give me some insight as to how i'd build out this scope line above you wrote, but with a dynamic association name in place of "engine". `scope = scope.where( Car.engine.arel_table[key].send predicate, value )`

Comment: as @AlistairIsrael suggested, if you have a finite set of possible search fields, you could use a lookup table - it could be a simple hash with association names as keys and scope names as values. If you really want an "automagic" scope, you could use : `joins( association_name ).where( reflect_on_association( association_name ).klass.arel_table[column].send predicate, value )`. However, you should be aware that such design is a bit dangerous because it is less predictable, so you should filter the arguments sent to such a method.

Comment: p.s. :if you want to know more about `reflect_on_association`, i think the best place is in the source : https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/reflection.rb .

Answer (score 0):

So, you want dynamic queries that end-users can specify at run-time (and can be stored & retrieved for later use)?

I think you're on the right track. The only detail is how you model and store your criteria. I don't see why the following won't work:

```
def self.using_conditions(conditions)
  joins(:car)
  crit = conditions.each_with_object({}) {|(field, op, value), m|
    m["#{field} #{op} ?"] = value
  }
  where crit.keys.join(' AND '), *crit.values
end
```

**CAVEAT** The above code *as is* is insecure and prone to SQL injection.

Also, there's no easy way to specify `AND` vs `OR` conditions. Finally, the simple `"#{field} #{op} ?", value` for the most part only works for numeric fields and binary operators.

But this illustrates that the approach can work, just with a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: yep, how you worded it is pretty much what I need. I am also worried about SQL injection, with doing something like this... is there a best practice/secure way of doing this? The only thing i can think of is doing some sort of validation on the fields entered to make sure they don't include any type of SQL injection

Comment: The fact that we use SQL parameters (`?`) already provides a level of defense against SQL injection of parameters for the `value`. If you model it such that the `field` and `op` values can't be directly supplied or edited by the user, then you can achieve further hardening. For example, instead of using `op` as `#{op}` directly, use an integer (or symbolic) `op_code`, and an internal lookup table, so, `#{ops[op_code]}`. The same technique can be used for the field names if you're working with a finite set of fields.

Comment: I like the operator lookup table idea... i'm going to give that a shot